# Value not displaying in the text box in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my View

```
<div class="datePick">
    <div class='input-group datePickerMin date datepickerC ' >
        <input value="
            <?php
                if( ! empty($task['due_date'])
                    && $task['due_date'] !='0000-00-00'){
                    echo date($this->session->userdata('default_date_format'),
                        strtotime($task['due_date']));}?>"
            <?php
                if($current_user_id ==  $task['user_id']):
            ?>
            name="edit_due_date" id="edit_due_date_<?php echo $task['task_id'];?>"
            <?php else:?>
                disabled
            <?php endif;?>
            class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="
            <?php echo lang('DUE_TASK')?>">
        <span class="input-group-addon datePickerIco">                  
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I will open my application this value is not displaying. But when I will Inspect it the value is showing in that,it means value is passing but not displaying

```
<input class="form-control"
    type="text" placeholder="Set due date"
    disabled="" value="19/05/2016">
```

I am Using bootstrap datetimepicker. The thing is that it is not selected because it is past. Eventhough if it is past,I need to display it

here it is

```
/* date time picker */
            $('.datetimepicker').each(function(){
                jQuery(this).datetimepicker({
                        minDate :today
                });
            })
```

The date selection is not showing if I select those details which I created in the past. I need to display those days even if it is created in the past. What Changes I should do so that It may select the date irrespective of the day which is created from now.

Answer (score 1):

you set minDate so its not allow past date

remove minDate :today  it will works

```
  $('.datetimepicker').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).datetimepicker({

            });
        })
```

Comment: Friend because of disabling minDate. It enabled all the dates. How I can rectify that

Comment: It is not selecting the past dates. The problem is that the selected date for a particular detail is not able to fetch if that date is in the past

Answer (score 0):

Your code may be a lot readable & simpler if your broke-off your conditional statements from the Input Field and use the values of your evaluations within the Field like so:

```
            <?php
                $dateValue  = "";
                $id         = "edit_due_date";
                $state      = "";
                if (!empty($task['due_date']) && $task['due_date'] != '0000-00-00') {
                    $dateValue = date($this->session->userdata('default_date_format'), strtotime($task['due_date']));
                }
                if ($current_user_id == $task['user_id']){
                    $id     = "edit_due_date_" . $task['task_id'];
                }else{
                    $state  = "disabled";
                }
            ?>



            <div class="datePick">
                <div class='input-group datePickerMin date datepickerC '>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name='edit_due_date' <?php echo $state;?> placeholder="<?php echo lang('DUE_TASK') ?>" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $dateValue; ?>">
                    <span class="input-group-addon datePickerIco">
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But can you please help me to sort out the issue